# What is the asymptotic runtime of the best known TSP solving algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, traveling-salesman

I always thought that TSP currently requires time exponential in the number of cities to solve.

> How, then, has [Concorde](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/concorde.html) optimally solved a TSP instance with
>   **85,900 cities**?!?

Is this a typo? Is the base of the exponential 1.0000000000000001 or similar? Was it an instance specifically constructed to be solvable easily? What *is* the asymptotic runtime of the best known TSP solving algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The worst case running time of Concorde or any other known method is exponential in the size of the input. However, sometimes [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) or other pruning techniques are effective and you are able to solve some, even large, instances pretty quickly. You should define exactly what you mean by TSP as there are many variants, and many algorithms with different worst case run times.

See the accepted answer in [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9241/5693) on CSTheory to see a list of algorithms.

Comment: The Concorde website claims that the problem instance was solved optimally. How can that be known for certain if heuristics were used?

Comment: @user16732 They probably use methods that prune the search tree safely, i.e. [branch & bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

Comment: Why does that not work for every instance?

Comment: @user16732 The time taken by B&B is still exponential in the worst case. The time depends on the structure of your input, and parameters of your search.

Comment: So, the conclusion is that it was a special instance that made it possible to B&B effectively, and in general, instances that large cannot be solved?

Comment: The *size* of an instance is not really what matters, but it's the *structure* of the instance. Even really large instances can be solved quickly, if the structure is easy. I don't know if Concorde even uses B&B, or some other similar methods. But this conclusion still holds.

Comment: @user16732 It seems to me you should read up on algorithms basics before concerning yourself with research-level material. For an explanation of branch & bound, see [my answer here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/branch-and-bound-explanation/1950#1950).